# Media query to turn site into mobile site

Tags: css, mobile-website

I've been looking at a few websites, in order to construct my own websites, and I've noticed that when you zoom in past a certain percentage, the website emulates a mobile display. No horizontal scrollbar appears, and everything fits onto the page, and only the page length increases.

Here are a few example websites - https://generalassemb.ly/, http://learnlayout.com/, http://dev.opera.com/

I'm not sure how they implement this is their design, and have searched the web for an explanation.

If possible, could you walk me through it with example CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the zoom, but with the current width of the window, ( At least in your examples, the same happens when you change your browser's window to a smaller size ) they are most likely using CSS media queries to apply conditional styles depending on the width.

Sample ( from first google result http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ )

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```